# Как использовать venv в pychram?

Tags: mysql, python, django, pycharm

Нужно подключить mysql в django. Я делал так `pip install mysql-python`. Такой способ выдает ошибку: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-331syeib/mysql-python`
Разработкой под python занимаюсь не так долго, но предполагаю что проблему исправит виртуальная среда, т.е. `venv`. Есть ли возможность использовать ее из коробки в pychram?
Версия `python 3`

Comment: В Pycharm есть поддержка создания и установки пэкэджей в venv из коробки, покопайтесь в меню с настройками интерпретаторов.

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему вы решили, что проблема в отсутствии venv. Без описания ошибки сложно понять, в чем дело. Попробуйте сначала обновить pip и setuptools.

Comment: @PavelGurkov тело вопроса к заголовку не имеет отношения. `mysql-python` не поддерживает Python 3.

Comment: @jfs ларчик просто открывался. Может быть, тогда стоит попросить переформулировать вопрос?

Comment: @PavelGurkov: автор может отдельный вопрос задать в зависимости от реальной проблемы, например, "как настроить django на использование mysql в Питон 3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть путь через "клики мышкой":
Preferences -> Project Interpreter -> шестеренка напротив интерпретатора -> Create VirtualEnv. Создаете, переключаетесь в нее (ставите venv созданную средой по умолчанию для проекта), ставите нужные модули.

Answer (score 1):

1. Открываешь консоль в pycharm.
2. Устанавливаешь virtualenv:

   $ [sudo] pip3 install virtualenv
3. Затем создание среды:

   $ virtualenv myenv
4. запускаешь:

   source myenv/bin/activate
5. Устанавливаешь нужные пакеты как обычно.

Все будет установлено в виртуальную среду.
Не забудь указать интерпретатору путь к python-3 из виртуальной среды.
А в настройках запуска проекта указать правильный интерпретатор.